# How to specify for the web.config to use a local path as URL source?

Tags: html, asp.net

I want my HTML pages to use a local path as an image's source in my development environment.

Something like:

`<img src="C:\localPath.jpg" alt="stf">`

Is there a configuration for the web.config to specify a specific folder as if it a CDN server?

Comment: No, this is not possible. And even if it were it would be a huge security risk.

Comment: Can specify relevant topics for that point so I will read about it?
I don't understand the security risk in that.